# How to add the cells in the table view like this in the image?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Hi all I want to add the cell in the table view as one touches on the row or section.I tried this by taking the sections and then clicking on the section will change the height of cell.But thats not working fine.

Here are the images ,that i want to accomplish[image: First Images show the cells or the sections]

[image: This is the how 2nd image will show after selecting in the first image]

Thanks in advance for everyone......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exact answer...but you can use this approach

You don't need to have sections.It can be don using custom cell with UILable & Uibutton(for +)

On button clicked event

-(IBAction)ShowDetails:(id)sender
{

```
[UITableView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UITableView setAnimationDuration:.5];
[UITableView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

[tableView reloadData];
```

[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

```
[UITableView commitAnimations];
```

}

add code to increase height cell

in

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

if (indexPath.row ==RowClicked)

return 100;//size according content you want to display;

}

return 40;

}

& in

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

check for that cell whose button is pressed & add UILabel for info u want to display in it.

Comment: Fine Amit I will give it a try.But suppose if i want to show more then one row then.I mean on the click of cell one say 2 rows and on the click of 2nd row say 6 rows.I mean different number of rows on different cell click.Then is this possible with your code,if so then how?Thanks dear

Comment: Yes the rows are still 4 ,i mean if i click on the our profile then there is one text to show,but when i click on the our mission or something else then there needs to show 3 or 4 rows below that.So is this possible with your idea

Answer (score 0):

It is an example of `Table View Animations and Gestures`.You can get a sample code for the same from Apple developer sample codes.[TableViewAnimation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010139)

Demonstrates how you can use animated updates to open and close sections of a `table view` for viewing, where each section represents a play, and each row contains a quotation from the play. It also uses `gesture recognizers` to respond to user input: * A `UITapGestureRecognizer` to allow tapping on the section headers to expand the section; * A `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` to allow dynamic changes to the height of table view rows; and * A `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to allow press-and-hold on table view cells to initiate an email of the quotation.

Comment: Yes I downloaded the sample code from the apple that is what i was using.But i am getting data from parsing and finding this sample code tough to send the array to this table.Can you provide me any idea how to do that